# For how long can Spanish Citizens visit USA without visa?

Tags: visas, usa, esta, spanish-citizens

I have a Spanish passport (Europe) and I would like to do an academic visit to a research center in the states.

The host destination (in USA) is not paying anything, I am granted by an European institution.

The grant is for 3 months and I am wondering if it is enough the ESTA to carry out the visit, taking into account that 7 months ago (last year) I visited the states for 12 days. If not, what would I need?

Comment: [Possibly related](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/is-it-legal-to-use-tourist-visa-waiver-for-academic-visits) on [academia.se]

Comment: Sorry, I've edited clarifying who is the grantor. The host is not paying anything during my visit.

Comment: I would direct the question to the International Student/Visiting Scholar office at the host institute. All US universities have one (though the name may vary slightly, or there may be separate ones for students and scholars). They tend to be very knowledgeable and can assist you with a visa application should that be necessary. Answering questions like this is literally their job.

Comment: I fully agree with @Johanna's excellent answer. That is exactly what you should do.